# Elementary row/column operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

When we are using elementary row operations in order to find reduced echelon form of a matrix, can we also use elementary column operations simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, elementary column operations change the reduced row echolon form of a matrix.
In fact, every matrix $A$ can be brought into the block-matrix form
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    _r & 0 \\
    0   & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
if both elementary row operations and elementary column operations are allowed.
(The number $r$ is precisely the rank of $A$.)